# Jquery autoscroll issue in Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, autoscroll

In our Form-builder, we use Drag & Drop, and Sortable.

After adding few element to the sortable container, while drag & drop, container need to auto scroll before drop. 
[image]

Comment: Have you activated the scroll option of your draggable element? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#scroll

Comment: Or the scroll option of your sortable element?http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: @Bouillou we activated scroll . but still issue occurs